# Programmatically verify signed dll's C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, digital-signature

I have a signed dll and want to verify its signature before I use it.
my application is written by C++. How can I get programmatically the dll's signature?

Comment: Read the dll in as a file, watch out for the begin of the signature (either by position or by a specific character/set of characters marking the beginning), read in all the characters until the end of the signature into a buffer, compare it with the signature you already had loaded into your program, done.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [WinVerifyTrust function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Dlls and PE are almost same except for 2 to 3 bytes difference in there header.
A full code example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384%28VS.85%29.aspx) (also applicable to dll).

Comment: thank for your reply. what does the VerifyEmbeddedSignature(LPCWSTR pwszSourceFile) expects to get? the name of the dll?

Comment: A DLL file is in PE (Portable Executable) format, there is NO difference.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN recommended way is to run SignTool which is part of CryptoAPI -

> SignTool returns command-line text that states the result of the signature check. Additionally, SignTool returns an exit code of zero for successful execution, one for failed execution, and two for execution that completed with warnings.

See [Using SignTool to Verify a File Signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388171%28v=vs.85%29) for details.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is [CAPICOM library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is [available as 32-bit redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25281) from Microsoft. The verification code can be as simple as:

```
CComPtr<Capicom::ISignedCode> pSignedCode;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pSignedCode.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Capicom::SignedCode)));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pSignedCode->put_FileName(CComBSTR(pszPath)));
HRESULT nVerifyResult = pSignedCode->Verify(ATL_VARIANT_FALSE);
```

You can also easily obtain additional information such as signer, certificate etc.

If you don't feel like using CAPICOM, MSDN suggests [alternate options to `SignedCode` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc778518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_crypto2_digital_signature_objects) used in code snippet above.